# Storyboard/XML/UIView how to avoid changing position

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, storyboard

I'm declaring a storyboard in xml,

When I cpoy/paste the xml into an actual sotryboard, some of my view will be moved, so the x, y width and height of elements will be different.

the design is meant to be iphone6 compliant & to handle autolayout. however, view like this one

```
<view contentMode="scaleAspectFit" fixedFrame="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cz19r018cejc92w3fw">
<rect key="frame" x="0" y="600" width="375" height="66"/>
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" heightSizable="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
```

will be changed to

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cz19r018cejc92w3fw">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="596" width="375" height="65"/>
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" heightSizable="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
```

notice that Y change from 600 to 596 and height from 66 to 65.

Any idea how to avoid such a behavior ?

EDIT:

I am using Xcode 9.2, storyboard is set as `View as: iPhone8`
I am generating the full storyboard itself, not only a view.
Here is a storyboard that produce the behavior.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="13771" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="cz19r024cjc5x0ecx">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="13772"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="cz19r024cjc5x0ecx-scene">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="cz19r024cjc5x0ecx" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="cz19r024cjc5x0ecx-top"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="cz19r024cjc5x0ecx-bottom"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" id="view-cz19r024cjc5x0ecx">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="672"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" heightSizable="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cz19r018cejc92w3fw">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0" y="600" width="375" height="66"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinX="YES" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES" heightSizable="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </view>
                    <extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout"/>
                    <nil key="simulatedTopBarMetrics"/>
                    <nil key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="placeholderId-cz19r024cjc5x0ecx" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: When you open the Storyboard - prior to pasting your xml into its source... at the bottom of the window you should see `View as: iPhone (something)". What do you currently see there?

Comment: And... are you using Xcode 8 or 9? and... are you pasting this as a subview of another view? If so, what else is there? It would probably help if you include the full Storyboard xml source...

Comment: good idea, please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 21 in your full xml is wrong:

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="672"/>
```

it should be:

```
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
```

`height="667"` instead of `height="672"`

Comment: well, it, indeed, explain my 5px change. thanks !! you saved me hours of work